# iPad Orientation change returns SIGABRT signal

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, orientation

I am making an app wherein when I load the app and change the orientation, it is able to handle the orientation. But if I tap on any TableViewCell in RootViewController to display a table in DetailViewController for a splitViewBased app and then change the orientation then my app crashes with SIGABRT and gives the following message :

```
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITableViewReorderingSupport count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e4eb30'
```

The method that I am writing to handle orientation is :

```
// Ensure that the view controller supports rotation and that the split view can therefore show in both portrait and landscape.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    //hot fix sometimes in multilevel bar button is shown in landscape mode.

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    }
    else {
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:self.appDelegate.rootPopoverButtonItem];
    }   
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You need to include more of your code. There are many different ways to crash an iOS app like this. You almost certainly have code in a `didRotateTo...` or `didRotateFrom...` method in one of your views that is generating this error.

Comment: I have placed the code which I have in my app to handle rotation

Comment: You're sending the message 'count' to '_UIUITableViewReorderingSupport'. What is that? What are you trying to count?

Comment: I obtain json array from an url and I equate the number of rows for a table to the count of that json array .

Answer (score 2):

You would most probably be using an array to load the contents to the table, and at the point of reloading or filling the table with contents, the array count might be 0 or the array instance would have lost its scope, and you would be trying to access it directly from cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate. If it is so, then try retaining the array, or allocating it.

Answer (score 0):

Add NSLog after the if and else to make sure it's reading each one and see if where the crash is. If there's the didRotateTo or didRotateFrom, add NSLog there too to see what's going on.

Also try just return YES: in the shouldAutorotate and nix the if/else to make sure it does rotate properly and there's nothing else getting in the way.

Lastly, check your Target > Supported Device Orientation to make sure all orientations are supported